# executemany method in mysql.connector with utf8mb4 charset not working (python)

Tags: python, mysql, database, utf8mb4, executemany

A few days ago I posted a problem regarding inserting emojis in a MariaDB database using the `mysql.connector` module in Python. Now after further investigations I was able to narrow the problem down. After changing the charset and collation of the connection properly I was able to execute single sql statements such as inserting and selecting values (example in the code below). In my use case I am inserting/updating a couple of thousand values at one moment. For efficiency, I use the `executemany` method which reduces the time drastically.

Before adding support for emojis I had no problems using the method. But whenever I use the method now I get an error which tells me that `utf8mb4` is an unknown encoding.

So this is where I was not able to get any further. I don't know if I am still doing something wrong or if there is an error in the `mysql.connector` module in python...
As mentioned previously just using the single execute method is not an option for me since it would take way too long. I was thinking of writing the multiple statements into one by my own. Since this option in not very good (especially for updating multiple rows) I would hope, that I can find a way to use the `executemany` method without the sacrifice of emoji support.

Code example:

```py
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    user="username",
    password="password",
    database="db_test",
    charset='utf8mb4',
    collation='utf8mb4_general_ci'
)

cnx.set_charset_collation('utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_general_ci')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

# This works without any problems
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('')")

cnx.commit()

# This works just fine too
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")

result = cursor.fetchall()

print(result)

# This does not work
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s)", ["", ""])

cnx.commit()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xampp\htdocs\py\db_test.py", line 28, in <module>
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s)", ["", ""])
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 652, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 582, in _batch_insert
    fmt = matches.group(1).encode(self._connection.charset)
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf8mb4
```

Comment: Works for me.  Can you add `SHOW CREATE TABLE test;` to the question?  And also `SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'db_test'`

Comment: OK the first statement retutrns the following: `CREATE TABLE 'test' ('name' varchar(32) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`;. And the second tatement returns this: `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME`: `utf8mb4`
`DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME`: `utf8mb4_general_ci`. This seems quite right to me.

Comment: Yes, my db has the same values, but no error.  My version of the connector is `Connector version (8, 0, 22, '', 1)` - `print(mysql.connector.version.VERSION)`

Comment: Printing the version results in the following for me: `(2, 2, 9, '', 0)`.

Comment: This is what I get when I use `pip show mysql.connector`:
Name: mysql-connector
Version: 2.2.9
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
Home-page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html
Author: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: GNU GPLv2 (with FOSS License Exception)
Location: c:\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

Comment: As it turns out using `pip install mysql.connector` installs an old version which has this but I guess. Now I used `pip install mysql-connector-python` and had no problem at all using the executemany method. Thanks a lot for helping me! This has been a pain for quite some time now.